# How to get reflections from video

Tags: compositing-nodes

I’m making a car and compositing it onto a scene, how do I get accurate reflections of trees and stuff on the car if the trees are on the video?

Answer (score 1):

using cycles render engine ->
Set up the mirror object. GO to material-> Select a Glossy Shader
using internal render engine->
simply use the mirror option in materials